# Turn several queries into one in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server called `schedule` that has the following columns (and others not listed):

| scheduleId | roomId | dateRegistered | dateFreed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4564 | 2 | 2022-12-25 | 2022-12-26 |
| 4565 | 3 | 2022-12-25 | 2022-12-27 |
| 4566 | 15 | 2022-12-26 | 2022-12-27 |
| 4567 | 2 | 2022-12-28 | 2022-12-31 |
| 4568 | 3 | 2022-12-28 | 2022-12-30 |

In some part of my app I need to show all the rooms occupied at a certain date.

Currently I run a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM schedule 
WHERE roomId = [theNeededRoom] AND dateFreed < [providedDate] 
ORDER BY dateFreed DESC
```

The thing is that I have to run that query in a for loop so that I get the information for every room.

I'm sure there has to be a better way to do this in a single query that returns a row for each of the different roomIds possible, how can I go about this?

Also, when the room is first registered, the dateFreed column has a null value, if I wanted to take this into account, how can I make the query so that, in the case the dateFreed value is null, that is the row that gets chosen?

Comment: Remove the `TOP (1)` and the filter on `roomId`?

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result? (Looks like you want a window function query.)

Comment: Is there a separate table that lists just the defined rooms?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TOP(1) WITH TIES`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-top/), while ordering on the last "*dateFreed*" date.

In order to have a "tied" value to match on, instead of ordering on "*dateFreed DESC*" we can use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function to generate a ranking on the same field (which will store 1 for each most recent "*dateFreed*" value, per "*roomId*").

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES * 
FROM schedule 
WHERE dateFreed < [providedDate] 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY roomId ORDER BY dateFreed DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        roomId AS rId,
        max(dateFreed) AS dateFreedMax
    FROM
        schedule s
    GROUP BY
        s.roomId
) AS t
WHERE
    t.dateFreedMax < [providedDate] 
    OR t.dateFreedMax IS NULL
```

Or

```
SELECT roomId
    FROM
        schedule s
    GROUP BY s.roomId, dateFreed 
HAVING
    max(dateFreed)<[providedDate]  OR dateFreed IS NULL
```